# Google Analytics Management API Java Package Batching not working as indended

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to roll out the same 10 goals to a large number of websites. I have the goals stored in toAddArray and in a loop, they will create or updated based off of the current site's number of goals. First I create the batch, then I loop through adding the goals to the batch (I omitted the Goal code because the writes are not failing) and then execute the batch.

**Code I am running**

```
        //Create batch from Analytics Object
        BatchRequest b = analytics.batch();
        // in loop determine create or update based off current Goal list size
        FOR LOOP IS HERE
        if(y < currentSize)
            {
                //some code for inserting the goal 
                analytics.management().goals().update(ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ID, ACTIVE_PROPERTY_ID, ACTIVE_PROFILE_ID, String.valueOf(y+1), toAddArray[y]).queue(b, setCallback("Successfully Added Goal"));
            }
            else{
                // Some code for when I update the goal 
                // Send to queue
                analytics.management().goals().insert(ACTIVE_ACCOUNT_ID, ACTIVE_PROPERTY_ID, ACTIVE_PROFILE_ID, toAddArray[y]).queue(b, setCallback("Successfully Added Goal"));
            }

           FOR LOOP ENDS
           //Execute the batch 
           b.execute();
```

**What is Happening**

When I am running this I get the callbacks for the 10 goals, the first 5-6 come back successful and the last 4 will come back with rate limit exceeded. To my knowledge, the whole point of the batching system is to compile the URLs into one hit and send them all at once to decrease the load on the server.

This system seems to be working more like a queueing system which has its place but does not help me decrease the number of writes I am working with. Since I am writing 10 goals to 1000 or so websites I am looking at 10k writes a day. With a limit of 500 writes per project a day that makes this a 20 day thing. If I only have a write per profile it would be a 2 day thing. I have requests in with the Google team to increase my API quotas and add the Goal update beta access to 5 more projects so I can start switching keys, but in the meantime, I want to understand if there is something I can do to get batching to work as one single write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance gains using batching are only called out for Permissions ([user management docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/user-management#batching)).

I believe you are correct when you say that the calls are made as if you made them one at a time. You're probably getting quota errors when you send 10 call all at once. I'm guessing it's the [1.5qps per Account ID write limit](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#write_requests)

If you need to make that many writes you may need to [implement exponential backoff.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/errors#backoff)

I hope this helps, and good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Josh. In the past I have been bucketing the hits myself with my own "queue" and then just putt the process to sleep periodically to not hit API limits.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/batching) is a link to the "Best Practices" page and it details how this can be used for many operations and is meant to decrease the number of hits to the API. It just seems like this Java class does not actually use the queue to generate the HTTP requests and batch them together. I am going to do that myself and pull request.